# Alphanumeric and Special characters RegEx 8-32 digit

Tags: java, regex, alphanumeric

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\@\#\$\%\&\*\(\)\-\_\+\]\[\'\;\:\?\.\,\!\^]+$
```

The output that is valid is :  `reahb543)(*&&!@#$%^kshABmhbahdxb!@$@#%6813741646`

This is the expression I have. But I need the value to be **8 to 32 digits** only.

So a valid string would be:

- 8 to 32 characters long
- including digits,alphabets,special characters

Comment: 8 to 32 **digits**? or characters? Please clarify.

Comment: java
8 to 32:  including digits,alphabets,special characters

Answer (score 4):

## Description

There are a couple things I would change in your expression:

- all the escaping of characters in the character class is unnecessary
- move the dash inside the character class to the end, as this character does have a special meaning inside the character class and needs to be at the end or beginning of the class
- add a look ahead to force the required number of digits in the string
- add a start string anchor to require the prevent the string from matching longer strings which may contain more digits then allowed

This expression will:

- require the string to contain between 8 and 32 digits, any more or less will not be allowed
- allow any number of characters from your character set (providing the other rules here are also true)
- allow numbers to appear as the first or last character of the string

`^(?=(?:\D*?\d){8,32}(?!.*?\d))[a-zA-Z0-9@\#$%&*()_+\]\[';:?.,!^-]+$`

[image]

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (between 8 and
                             32 times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \D*?                     non-digits (all but 0-9) (0 or more
                               times (matching the least amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ){8,32}                  end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more
                               times (matching the least amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-zA-Z0-                any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z',
  9@\#$%&*()_+\]\[';:?     '0' to '9', '@', '\#', '$', '%', '&', '*',
  .,!^-]+                  '(', ')', '_', '+', '\]', '\[', ''', ';',
                           ':', '?', '.', ',', '!', '^', '-' (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

## Example

[Live Demo](http://www.rubular.com/r/PndynDioSv)

**Samples**

```
reahb)(*&&!@#$%^kshABmhbahdxb!@$@#%1234567   = bad
reahb)(*&&!@#$%^kshABmhbahdxb!@$@#%12345678  = good
1234reahb)(*&&!@#$%^kshABmhbahdxb!@$@#%5678  = good
1234reahb)(*&&!@#$%^kshABmhbahdxb!@$@#%5678901234567890123456789012   = good
1234reahb)(*&&!@#$%^kshABmhbahdxb!@$@#%56789012345678901234567890123  = bad
reahb)(*&&!@12345678901234567890123456789012#$%^kshABmhbahdxb!@$@#%   = good
reahb)(*&&!@123456789012345678901234567890123#$%^kshABmhbahdxb!@$@#%  = bad
```

---

## Or

If you're looking to allow only 8-32 characters of any type from your character class then will work:

`^[a-zA-Z0-9@\#$%&*()_+\]\[';:?.,!^-]{8,32}$`

[image]